# file_put_contents , failed to open stream: No such file or directory Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I just want to run my client's project in to my local and having this problem.

**ErrorException in compiled.php line 6301: file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\tiger\storage/framework/views/111182673e168569a2371e23629d9c08): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

it is something like permission issue .. and i am windows user don't know how to figure it ... experts can u help me ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: di you try to clear laravel cache and composer dump-autoload.

Comment: its almost never a permission issue on windows, unless you have a very wierd setup

Comment: clean the cash and file_put_contents(str_replace("\","/",$filename))

Comment: yes i did php artisan cache:clear and dump-autoload

Comment: where should i do  file_put_contents(str_replace("\","/",$filename)) ??  volkinc

Comment: Go to ```htdocs\tiger\bootstrap\cache``` and then rename the file ```config.php``` to other(e.g> ```config.old.php```). Now run ```php artisan cache:clear``` and ```php artisan serve``` I think this will help you :)

Answer (score 22):

I had the same exact problem, try this

```
chmod -R guo+w storage

php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 18):

In case anyone here is using Homestead like me, you can run into the same issue using PHPUnit.

When you run `php artisan config:cache`, Laravel hardcodes some paths in the cache. If you run it on your Homestead VM, it uses those paths. If you run it from your workstation, it uses those paths. You should make your cache from the Homestead VM and then execute your tests from there as well to avoid cache problems.

You can tell when the cache needs to be cleared by looking at the file path that PHPUnit tries to use. If it's not a valid path on the machine you're running the command from, you need to rebuild your cache.

Comment: Precisely my issue: ran `config:cache` in local machine, which broke the Homestead paths. Thank you :)

Comment: I was having trouble, I solved it, and was ready to write a Stack Overflow answer.  You beat me to it.

Comment: thank you very much i was wondering why my database.php was not updating, but after running this command everything is working fine now!

Answer (score 7):

This solves the problem

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: After running this command, my page load worked without the `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` error. But I'd love to know the root cause of *why* this problem ever happens so that I can prevent it from ever happening again.

Comment: @Ryan did you find the answer ?

Comment: @VishalParkash No

Comment: @Ryan if you are still struggling to find a solution please try this command: **composer clear-cache**, this command worked for me after trying all the solutions

Comment: @VishalParkash Thanks. But I’d already fixed the symptom and was trying to understand the root cause.

Answer (score 7):

```
php artisan config:cache
```

This code clear the cache and delete cache files.

Answer (score -5):

Inside the folder C:\xampp\htdocs\tiger\storage/framework/views
make a file named 111182673e168569a2371e23629d9c08

now refresh your browser 
this should solve your problem in window 
for linux users you should provide permission to for this file